# Differences in scheduling between Mesos and Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling, mesos

*Foreword:* My question is somewhat related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705201/whats-the-difference-between-apaches-mesos-and-googles-kubernetes), but I'd like to go deeper on the particular aspect of scheduling.

Apart from the fact that Kubernetes's scheduling is *centralized* and Mesos's scheduling is *decentralized*, following a two-step process, what are the differences between the scheduling algorithms of both projects?

I've been using Kubernetes for half a year now, and I've never used Mesos in practice. I understand the concept of *resource offerings* but I cannot establish a comparison between Mesos and Kubernetes scheduling algorithms, mainly because I don't have deep knowledge of both tools' implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is comparable. Kubernetes can be run as a Mesos framework. Its scheduler is described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/scheduler_algorithm.md). It base on filtering and ranking the nodes.

Mesos two step scheduling is more depend on framework algorithm.

1. Mesos presents the offers to the framework based on [DRF algorithm](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Ematei/papers/2011/nsdi_drf.pdf). Frameworks could be prioritized as well by using roles and weights.
2. Frameworks decide which task to run based on give offer. Every framework can implement its own algorithm for matching task with offer. [This is a NP hard problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43448790/1387612)

**Appendix** Quote from https://medium.com/@ArmandGrillet/comparison-of-container-schedulers-c427f4f7421

[image]

> **Monolithic scheduling**
>
> Monolithic schedulers are composed of a single
> scheduling agent handling all the requests, they are commonly used in
> high-performance computing. A monolithic scheduler generally applies a
> single-algorithm implementation for all incoming jobs thus running
> different scheduling logic depending on job types is difficult. Apache
> Hadoop YARN [55], a popular architecture for Hadoop that delegates
> many scheduling functions to per-application components, is a
> monolithic scheduler architecture due to the fact that the resource
> requests from application masters have to be sent to a single global
> scheduler in the resource master.
>
> **Two-level scheduling**
>
> A two-level
> scheduler adjusts the allocation of resources to each scheduler
> dynamically using a central coordinator to decide how many resources
> each sub-cluster can have, it is used in Mesos [50] and was used for
> Hadoop-on-Demand (now replaced by YARN). With this architecture, the
> allocator avoids conflicts by offering a given resource to only one
> framework at a time and attempts to achieve dominant resource fairness
> by choosing the order and the sizes of the resources it offers. Only
> one framework is examining a resource at a time thus the concurrency
> control is called pessimistic, a strategy that is less error-prone but
> slower compared to an optimistic concurrency control offering a
> resource to many frameworks at the same time.
>
> **Shared-state scheduling**
>
> Omega grants each scheduler full access to the entire cluster,
> allowing them to compete in a free-for-all manner. There is no central
> resource allocator as all of the resource-allocation decisions take
> place in the schedulers. There is no central policy-enforcement
> engine, individual schedulers are taking decisions in this variant of
> the two-level scheme. By supporting independent scheduler
> implementations and exposing the entire allocation state of the
> schedulers, Omega can scale to many schedulers and works with
> different workloads with their own scheduling policies [54].

Comment: Which one does Kubernetes use? Shared-state?

Comment: Monolith scheduling