# About docker's orchestra tool that can maximize utilization of server resources

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mesos, docker-swarm, nomad

In order to make full use of server resources, 
I would like to consider the docker orchestra tool.

For example, there are three containers in the A server, but as long as there is room in the B server, it is only necessary to control such that one container is moved to the B server.

What is the term meaning such a function?

Can you use kubernetes, swarm, mesos, nomad like the above functions?

Answer (score 0):

[Maximizing utilization is in general a NP-hard problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43448790/1387612).

Mesos is a two step scheduler. Resources usage could be control by a framework. Mesos only present resources and it's on framework side to accept them or not. This means you can implement any algorithm to maximize utilization of cluster. What's more Mesos gives you oprtiunity to monitor slack resources and use them too with [oversubscription](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/oversubscription/).

In Kubernetes you also can plug your own scheduler. Kubernetes is one step scheduler but you can have [multiple schedulers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/) at once. See documentation for this: [advanced scheduling in Kubernetes](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/03/advanced-scheduling-in-kubernetes.html)